# Get 'Unknown type' when looking up particular DNS record types

Tags: node.js, dns

I'm on node.js 0.12.2.

When I call

```
dns.resolve('example.com', 'SOA', function (err, result) {})
```

I get an error:

```
 Unknown type SOA.
```

The same happens when I call `dns.resolveSoa()`.

Every other record type works, except for this.

Is it just me or doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

It's not just you. I got the same error, even though [the docs clearly state that SOA records are supported](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolve_hostname_rrtype_callback). Thankfully, I found an alternative: [native-dns](https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns). Here's an example that should get you on the right track. First:

```
$ npm install native-dns
```

Then, in node:

```
var dns = require('native-dns');

var question = dns.Question({
  name: 'www.google.com',
  type: 'SOA',
});

var req = dns.Request({
  question: question,
  server: { address: '8.8.8.8', port: 53, type: 'udp' },
  timeout: 1000,
});

req.on('timeout', function () {
  console.log('Timeout in making request');
});

req.on('message', function (err, answer) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.log(answer);
});

req.on('end', function () {
  console.log('Finished processing request');
});

req.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

For SOA records, this now works:

```
var util = require('util'),
    dns = require('dns'),
    resolve = util.promisify(dns.resolve),

var soaResults = await resolve(domainName, 'SOA')

{ nsname: 'ns10.dnsmadeeasy.com',
hostmaster: 'dns.dnsmadeeasy.com',
serial: 2009016889,
refresh: 43200,
retry: 3600,
expire: 1209600,
minttl: 1200 }
```

However if you need to look up another record type that isn't in the [list of supported types](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolve_hostname_rrtype_callback) - for example, I need to look up CAA recoerds - the `native-dns` module mentioned in the other answer will help.